# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext error while running Application test code

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[image]
I'm trying to write a Spring boot application, but when I run my code it gives me

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration

This error is on Application test file. Can you help me to solve this problem?

[image]

Here are my codes:

**Service:**

```
package tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Repository:**

```
package tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.data.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.data.entity.Player;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface IPlayerRepository extends CrudRepository <Player, Integer>
{
    Optional<Player> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.controller;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.data.entity.Player;
import tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.service.PlayerService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/players")
public class PlayerController
{
    private final PlayerService m_playerService;

    public PlayerController(PlayerService playerService) {
        m_playerService = playerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("player/username")
    public ResponseEntity<Player> findByUsername(@RequestParam(name = "uname") String username)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.of(m_playerService.findPlayerByUsername(username));
    }

}

**Player Service Helper:**

    package tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.data.dal;
    
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.data.entity.Player;
    import tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.data.repository.IPlayerRepository;
    
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    @Component
    public class PlayerServiceHelper {
        private final IPlayerRepository m_playerRepository;
    
        public PlayerServiceHelper(IPlayerRepository playerRepository)
        {
            m_playerRepository = playerRepository;
        }
    
        public Optional<Player> findPlayerByUsername(String username)
        {
            return m_playerRepository.findByUsername(username);
        }
    
    }
```

**Player:**

```
package tr.edu.altinbas.swe.app.player.data.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    public int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    public LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name = "register_date", nullable = false)
    public LocalDateTime registerDate = LocalDateTime.now();

}
```

Comment: Can you please show me your `Main class`, `Repository` and `Service`? Add full stack trace in your question.

Comment: I am saying add it into your question not in comment. And add full stack trace as well

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie at coding so I dont know what to do clearly. I edited the post, I hope it is understandable now.